# How can I get all the title of post on the New York Times page

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How can I get all the post on this page  
[New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/) using python web scraping technics

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")

posts = soup.select(".css-1yjtett")

bullet = 1

for post in posts:

    posts = soup.select(".css-1yjtett.css-1ez5fsm esl82me1")

    print(str(bullet) +" -"+ post.select_one(".css-1w0yruz 
           esl82me0").getText())

    bullet += 1
```

I get no result please.

Comment: What do you mean by all post?

Comment: all the post titles

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `response.text` contains what you think it should contain? Have you verified that `posts` contains what you think it should contain? Have you verified that `post.select_one(...)` is returning what you think it should? It doesn't look like you've done anything at all to try to solve this problem before asking a question. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: Nope I will start the process

Comment: I couldnot find the source of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses CSS Selector `section:not(section[data-testid="block-Briefings"]) article`: it will find all articles that aren't under section `Briefings`. Then we iterate these articles and find all tags `<h2>`, our headlines:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")

posts = soup.select('section:not(section[data-testid="block-Briefings"]) article')

for i, post in enumerate(posts, 1):
    print('{: <4}{}'.format(str(i) + '.', post.find('h2').text))
```

Prints:

```
1.  Climate Change Threatens World’s Food Supply, United Nations Warns
2.  A quarter of humanity faces looming water crises.
3.  On a Day Set Aside for Healing, Trump Stokes Divisions
4.  Senator Elizabeth Warren of Massachusetts said that she believed Mr. Trump was a white supremacist.
5.  Andrew Yang became the ninth Democratic presidential candidate to qualify for the next debate.
6.  JPMorgan Kept Epstein as a Client Despite Warnings
7.  The mogul behind Victoria’s Secret accused Mr. Epstein in a letter of misappropriating “vast sums of money.”
8.  He’s a Veteran of Upheaval, Molded by Ferguson’s Traumas. He’s 7.
9.  The Unlikely American Target of China’s Conspiracy Theories on Hong Kong
10. The Secret History of ‘Easter Eggs’
11. Was Trump’s El Paso Visit a Turning Point?
12. Quiz: Let Us Predict Whether You’re a Democrat or a Republican
13. Trump’s Rhetoric and Conservative Denial
14. ‘The Squad’ Is the Future of the Democratic Party
15. Trump Has Dragged Us Into the Gutter
16. How to Force 8Chan, Reddit and Others to Clean Up
17. Lebanon’s Blasphemy Wars Strike a Popular Rock Band
18. Donald Trump’s Outrageous 2020 Advantage
19. Why Doesn’t America Know More About Gun Safety?
20. ‘It Worked in Panama.’ This Is Not True.
21. Helping Students With Disabilities
22. Can Britain’s No. 1 Bookseller Save Barnes & Noble?
23. Running to Put San Quentin Behind Him
24. You Make the Call: East Harlem or Murray Hill?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use findAll with tag "Span" and Class "balancedHeadline" and then get the text out of it, something like below

```
post_titles_list = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "balancedHeadline"})
for post_title in post_titles_list:
    ......
```